# I need to exclude certain products from a general discount

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes, offers

I have a discount that subtracts 50 from the every total amount in the cart that's above 250.
I did it in the cart rule using this method:

[image]

How do I exclude certain products from this cart rule?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to exclude specific SKUs like this:

[image]

Reference https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-create.html#step-2-describe-the-conditions and https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/promotions.html. Worth noting that attributes should have the option 'use in promo rules' in order to be usable in conditions.