# Can't find the option to exclude SKU

Tags: cart, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, offers

I can't find this screen:
[image]

I'm trying to exclude an SKU from a cart rule,
How do I get to it?

I got here:
[image]

And I can't see where there's an option to choose SKU.

Comment: click on the green + button to add the next rule which will give you the sku option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to exclude certain products from a general discount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340817/i-need-to-exclude-certain-products-from-a-general-discount)

Answer (score 0):

In second screen click on + exact after "if an item....." and you will get option to select.